# Traversing a graph and meeting a certain criteria?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-theory

I want to  find the path between two vertices of a graph grid (A x B size, with 1x1 cells) (a1, b1) and (a2, b2) but with **additional criterion of avoiding some n forbidden nodes** (x1, y1), (x2, y2) as far away as possible  from any one node to reach the destination. This means for all potential paths, the closest distance to any forbidden node should be the largest. The node positions are integers but the distance away from the nodes can be float numbers.

I would think the shortest path algorithms like Dijkstra's probably wouldn't matter a lot since the shortest path could end up traversing one of the n forbidden nodes. But then how can I factor in the "furthest distance away" from the nodes factor? My thoughts:

1. I could try to average positions of the forbidden nodes, but I have managed to come up with one counter example that this might end up traversing one of the nodes
2. The alternative way is to simply compute all possible paths and find the one with the furthest distance from any one forbidden node. This might mean using some dynamic programming approach.
3. We can also tabulate the min distance from any one forbidden nodes at every node in the graph, and choose the path that gives the greatest distance at each step.
4. Other thoughts: might have to use disjoint sets and MSTs?

My potential solutions seem to incur very high time complexity and I thought this kind of problem should be quite common (people probably have thought of this before). Is there a standard practice or way to approach this kind of problems optimally?

Comment: If there are multiple paths that have the same smallest distances from a forbidden node how do you rank them? Shortest distance? or not ranked?

Comment: Any reason you can't just use Dijkstra's algorithm but instead of distance you use `- min(distance to each forbidden node)` as the cost function when evaluating the next node to visit? Or if you want smallest distance amongst equals, track that also (a tuple) and use it as the tie-breaker?

Comment: I agree with @IanMercer. "Shortest" doesn't need to be Euclidean distance. Think about how to assign edge weights that get the result you  want. Note however that Ian's exact suggestion won't work. You'll need to use Bellman-Ford or some other algorithm that handles negative weights. Dijkstra's doesn't.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49353278/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/89511/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: @D.W. I thought the question was more appropriate at the CS forum since there was no code involved, but couldn't delete the post here due to the upvotes.

Comment: OK.  If you have that problem again, rather than cross-posting, you can flag the post for moderator attention and ask the moderators to migrate it, and wait for them to migrate it (without cross-posting).  Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us about the context where you encountered this problem?  Can you credit the source in the question?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Pick a distance D and remove from the graph all nodes within distance D of the forbidden nodes. Find out if the source and destination are still connected. Use binary chop to find the largest possible D still leaving the source and destination connected. The path from source to destination on this graph is the path you want.